# save form data to session before open modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jquery and javascript.
I have a form X which have 2 button, 1 for submit form X and 1 for open modal(contain form Y). but when I submit form Y, data in form X is lost.
Is it possible when I click button for openning modal, I save data form X to session with jquery post? how should I do it?

```
<form action="" method="post" id="fx">
  <input type="text" name="fx1">
  <input type="text" name="fx2">
  <input type="button" name="open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalSatuanKerjaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="" id="fy">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tambah Satuan Baru</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Satuan</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tsatuan[]" placeholder="Satuan" id="sat" required autofocus></input>                         
            <input type='hidden' name='page' value='pekerjaan'>
            <input type='hidden' name='mpage' value='satuan'>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="btnSatuan" class="btn btn-primary" name="tambah" value="T">Simpan</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Keluar</button>        
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use ajax call to save data of formx before formy...but if formy open without reload page. then formx data will be accessible,,, use$(#formid) to get data from both the forms.

Comment: Yes, its is possible to have POST request at the time of opening the modal (it can be async or sync call depending upon your requirement) and then save the necessary data at backend or may be session.

Comment: Best way if it fits into your requirement....instead of submitting Y form directly submit it through ajax call and then close the modal once form Y get submit...in this way you can submit the Form y and your Fom X data will get retain.

Comment: I need to show data submitted through form Y in form X. is it possible?